# numpy method for tensors in TensorFlow 2.x and eager execution

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

Using TensorFlow 2.4.1 on colab

Running this code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar100
import numpy as np

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels))
for (train, label) in train_dataset.take(1):
    print(label)
    print(label.numpy()[0])

# tf.Tensor([19], shape=(1,), dtype=int64)
# 19
```

This is all fine but when trying this with the filter method for keras.Dataset objects in the code below, the numpy method does not work:

```
def filter_classes(dataset, classes):
    def match_class(data, label):
        print(label)      
        print(label.numpy()[0])            
        return label.numpy()[0] in classes
    return dataset.filter(match_class)

cifar_classes = [0, 29, 99] 
train_dataset = filter_classes(train_dataset, cifar_classes)

# Tensor("args_1:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int64)
# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

From reading some of the related questions, the error seems to be due to the latter tensor not being eager executed.

1. Does the attribute in the tensor "arg_1:0" rather than being a numpy array signify that the tensor has not been evaluated?
2. With the filter method, is it by design that the tensors within the dataset objects do not get evaluated eagerly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf.data.Dataset functions do not run in EagerMode for performance reasons. You can't use the `.numpy` method in a function used by a `tf.data.Dataset`.

In your case, you can use a combination of `tf.math.equal` and `tf.math.reduce_any` to filter your dataset and keep only the desired classes:

```
ds_filtered = train_dataset.filter(lambda x:tf.math.reduce_any(tf.equal(x,cifar_classes)))
```